# Como fazer que para cada dia a imagem de background seja diferente?

Tags: php, html, css

Como é possível fazer que cada dia da semana seja uma imagem de background diferente ?

Comment: [Isso já foi resolvido na stack em inglês, porém baseando-se no color background, mas a idéia é a mesma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30837287/change-background-color-of-webpage-according-to-day-of-the-week?rq=1)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda vou dar uma olhada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`strftime('%A')`** -  retorna representação textual completa do dia `Sunday até Saturday`

Atribua a variável `$dia` o valor de `strftime('%A')`e dependendo do dia imprima o nome da imagem como complemento do `url` da propriedade `background-image` da folha de estilo

```
<style type="text/css">
body{background-image: url("http://dominio.com/diretorio/<?php
$dia = strftime('%A');

if($dia == 'Monday') echo 'image1';
elseif($dia == 'Tuesday') echo 'image2';
elseif($dia == 'Wednesday') echo 'image3';
elseif($dia == 'Thursday') echo 'image4';
elseif($dia == 'Friday') echo 'image5';
elseif($dia == 'Saturday') echo 'image6';
elseif($dia == 'Sunday') echo 'image7';
?>.png")}
</style>
```

Comment: Obrigado deu certo

Answer (score 0):

Nesse caso, a solução serve para alterar a cor de fundo, porém o conceito é o mesmo para a imagem.

```
switch($day) {
    case 'Monday':
        $bg_color = "red";
        break;
    case 'Tuesday':
        $bg_color = "blue";
        break;
    case 'Wednesday':
        $bg_color = "blue";
        break;
    case 'Thursday':
        $bg_color = "gray";
        break;
    case 'Friday':
        $bg_color = "yellow";
        break;
    case 'Saturday':
        $bg_color = "green";
        break;
    case 'Sunday':
    default:
        $bg_color = "black";
        break;
}

echo "<div style='background-color:$bg_color'>Welcome to my Homepage</div>";
```

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30837287/change-background-color-of-webpage-according-to-day-of-the-week?rq=1)